# Would it be incorrect to use “could” and “might” in the same sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs

Would it be incorrect to use “could” and “might” in the same sentence?

For example:

> It could be that Joseph might come this afternoon.

Since *could* and *might* are both stating a possibility, it seems kind of redundant, but is this okay grammatically?

Comment: It sounds fine to me. :)

Comment: Grammatically, it is impeccable. What you are talking about is semantics, not grammar. (And redundancy as such is neither grammatically nor semantically incorrect. It's merely redundant.)

Comment: *"Could it possibly be that Joseph might actually come this afternoon?"*

Comment: In some Southern US dialects, you could even use them as a combined modal: "Joseph might could come this afternoon".

Comment: @tylerharms That might could be, perhaps. However, it's not permitted in formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

Grammar has no objection to such a sentence. It is the semantics that matter here, if any.

This structure may be used in a context where *could* owes itself to one reason unrelated to that of *might*. A little clarification follows.

*He is so excited, what is it all about?*
*It could be that Joseph might come this afternoon.*

The reason for his being excited is likely that …  --> *could be*

Joseph is likely to come …  --> *might come*

The two are unrelated. Changing either will change the meaning or at least lead to ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

It is awkward.  Since *could* already indicates possibility, *might* should be replaced with *will* for a better sentence expressing possibility in the future.

> It could be that Joseph will come this afternoon.

Or change it to read

> Joseph might come this afternoon.

and simplify things.